# Finding the maximum number among 10 Areas in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in this C# language. I got stuck on finding the maximum area among ten of them and the the question prompts the user to compute ten areas of a circle and display the maximum.

Comment: post the code you tried so far

Comment: " finding the maximum area among ten of them " -> how is the area defined? how do you calculate the area?
"user to compute ten areas " -> please explain exactly how the area is supposed to be computed. Have you tried already to program something?

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<int> Areas = new List<int>() {
                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
            };

            int maxArea = Areas.Max();
```

Put all your areas into a List of integers and then use `.Max()` to find the largest :)